# Syntax Error when adding a LEFT JOIN to a SELECT-FROM-WHERE

Tags: mysql, left-join, mysql-5.7

`inscription`

[image: "inscription" table]

`diver`

[image: "diver" table]

This is OK:

```
SELECT id_membre, id_sortie, id_diver, licence, mail, actif
FROM inscription
WHERE id_sortie = 4071
```

When I add the LEFT JOIN it crashes:

```
SELECT id_membre, id_sortie, id_diver, licence, mail, actif
FROM inscription
WHERE id_sortie = 4071
LEFT JOIN diver ON inscription.licence = diver.licence;
```

> `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LEFT JOIN diver ON inscription.licence = diver.licence LIMIT 0, 30' at line 3`

Comment: `WHERE id_sortie = 4071` comes after the join . See [JOIN Clause](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html)

Comment: Order of clauses in SQL is not flexible. Read a tutorial and memorize the order.

Comment: Please ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question. Please either ask re 1 bad query/function with obligatory [mre], including why you think it should return something else or are unsure at the 1st subexpression that you get what you expect or are stuck, justified by reference to authoritative documentation, or ask about your overall goal giving working parts you can do with justification & a [mre--then misunderstood code doesn't belong. But please ask about unexpected behaviour 1st because misconceptions get in the way of your goal. [ask] [Help] Basic questions are faqs.

Comment: Debug questions require a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code including initialization; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For SQL include DDL & tabular initialization code. For debug that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) Please avoid social & meta commentary in posts.

Comment: You said "with the column `actif` from table `diver`" but that is wrong, you joined on  `licence`. That is why commentary/comments repeating code in prose is unhelpful. Also one reason why a [mre] is obligatory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct syntax :

```
SELECT id_sortie, id_diver, inscription.licence, mail, actif
FROM inscription
LEFT JOIN diver ON inscription.licence = diver.licence
WHERE inscription.id_sortie = 4071;
```

Comment: Code-only answers are poor. Explain what the problem was & why the post answers the question. [answer] PS Please delete & flag obsolete comments.